# Materials looking too dark

Tags: texturing, materials

After creating objects and applying the textures, I seem to have an issue where the material appears too dark.

The end result:

[image]

I know this isn't just because lights in blender as the same thing happens, when I import it to my 3D environment. How could I solve this? I managed to do it for the floor, but I can't remember how I did it.

Material settings:
[image]

Normals
[image]

Texture settings

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project or your textures or render settings.

Comment: Hi, thanks @cegaton . I've updated the post, is there anything else I could provide?

Comment: The top one is too dark @MrZak. I've been fiddling around with those settings, that's why they were at that state

Comment: Could it be that I need to modify something within the UV map menu?

Comment: What does the source texture for that top mesh look like? If the result is too dark UV map barely could be the reason though settings aren't shown on the screenshot and you might check if UV map is set to be used (if any) and scaling is set to reasonable value in the rollout there

Comment: https://imgur.com/Y75NKBH This is how it looks in the UV viewer

Comment: How would i check if the UV map is set to be used?

Comment: Settngs to use UV map are in Mapping rollout hidden on your screenshot. However from the first screenshot it looks like texture is there mapped fine but it's just black. Did you try to render the scene? How does it look like? Did you try to apply scale for that object with it selected in Object mode and pressing Ctrl+A > Scale, then recalculating normals in Edit mode? If you want anyone to look into your file you can upload it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit the question with link